# Instantiating an object, but using curly brackets instead of the default constructor?

Tags: c#, .net

I've come across the following code:

```
var process = new Process
{
     StartInfo =
     {
          Arguments = arguments,
          FileName = applicationPath,
          UseShellExecute = false,
          RedirectStandardOutput = true,
          CreateNoWindow = true
     }
};
```

I found it confusing: why are you able to omit the () after Process? I'm assuming this just instantiates the process object, and sets StartInfo on it, but I wasn't aware you could use this kind of syntax.

MSDN shows something similar in a traditional syntax:

```
Process myProcess = new Process();

try
{
    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\HelloWorld.exe";
    myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    myProcess.Start();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Comment: http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/csharp-3.0/object-initializers/  and  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Comment: Your assumption is correct.

Comment: It's called object initializer... what exactly is your question on here?

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) talks about it too. By the way, What is your question, What it is or why this feature exists in the language?

Comment: What it is - I'll check the links posted and hopefully they'll explain the feature to me!

Comment: I guess why it exists in the language would be interesting to know as well. Is it just to placate developers with differing coding styles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This notation implicitly calls the default constructor and allows you a shortcut for the initialization of instance fields/properties.

You can also explicitly call the default constructor

```
var process = new Process()
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        Arguments = arguments,
        FileName = applicationPath,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    }
};
```

Or any other constructor

```
var listener = new System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener(true)
{
    TraceOutputOptions = TraceOptions.Timestamp
};
```

You should get used to this kind of instantiation